# starting jboss 4.2.3, segmentation fault

Tags: java, linux, jboss

We have several machines running the same code, but for some reason some do not run a specific version of it (these machine do run nicely with previous versions of our code). The rest of the machines run nicely with the problematic version.

It seems like Jboss just crashes for some reason, the last output line is:

> WARN  [config] Unable to process deployment descriptor for context
>   '/lib'

and when running it without the jboss start/stop script it ends with:

> [1]+  Segmentation fault

I'm using openJdk 1.6.0_18 on all machines.